# Drawing a sphere with given Origin (Voxel Engine)

Tags: c#, geometry, voxel

I've been desperately attempting to create a sphere tool in my voxel engine. I know the general function for creating a sphere:

```
public bool getPoint (int x, int y, int z) {
    return (x*x+y*y+z*z < r*r) ? true : false;
}
```

This function will create a sphere assuming the origin is at (0, 0, 0). Yet I want to be able to create a sphere with a custom origin (or user-defined) say the origin is at (10, 10, 10). How would I modify this function to move the origin to a different position?

Comment: Short version: subtract 10 from your coordinates before doing your math. You're applying a negative world translation to compensate for the object really moving. This has nothing to do with "creating" spheres, nor with voxel theory though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `ox, oy, oz` be the center of your sphere. Then you just subtract the center from `x, y, z` before doing your computation:

```
public bool getPoint (int x, int y, int z, int ox, int oy, int oz)
{
    x -= ox;
    y -= oy;
    z -= oz;
    return (x*x+y*y+z*z < r*r);
}
```

Note that the expression `expr ? true : false` is equivalent to `expr` regardless of what `expr` is.